# Is there a way to turn a flat image into layers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to make a timeline with the same format as shown here:

[image: http://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/preview/mmwrhtml/figures/m5907a1f.gif]

What is the quickest way to turn this into a layered image in Photoshop so I can change the text for each date?  Could someone help me create this PSD?

Comment: You probably don't want to build this in PhotoShop at all. This is best handled by something like Adobe Illustrator, Inkscape or the like.

Answer (score 6):

No there is no way of turning a flat image into layers in Adobe Photoshop,

You can not edit this image, you have to create it again in Photoshop, after creating this file, save this in .psd format, after this you'll be able to edit text anytime anywhere. but first you have to create this by manually typing,

and fastest way is :
open this image in photoshop erase all text and write your own, then save it in .psd format for future use.

hope this will help

Comment: @LookingForHelp Depending on the image and what you want into different layers, but you can in fact turn flat image into layers. As far as the text goes..there are OCR programs that detect text in image but I wouldnt bother at all.. ( what im saying is, you pretty much have to re-write the text. )  But still you _can_ turn everything in this image into their own layers.. though first you might want to make the white background transparent. In this case basically Select an area and `Ctrl + Shift + J`

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how clearly defined the item(s) you wish to create new layers from. In your example it looks like the answer above is the best answer. However if you have a simple image or logo you can use the Magic Wand tool to select an item, right-click, and then select 'Layer via Cut' or 'Layer via Copy'